# what does get_conn_type function in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I had ejabberd 13.12, all works great until I physically moved server machine to another network, then jabber server start encounting crashes. (the same types and details of networks)

`CRASH REPORT Process <0.4260.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: call to undefined function 
ejabberd_socket:get_conn_type({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.5852>,<0.4259.0>}) in p1_fsm:terminate/7 line 733
2014-01-23 09:34:42.548 [error] <0.330.0> Supervisor ejabberd_c2s_sup had child undefined started with 
{ejabberd_c2s,start_link,undefined} at <0.4260.0> exit with reason call to undefined function 
ejabberd_socket:get_conn_type({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.5852>,<0.4259.0>}) in context child_terminated`

after machine migration the statuses of users was changed randomly.

I tried reinstall jabber server and I used ejabberd 2.1.13 compiled from scratch - what give me the same errors while using jabber.

function is:

```
get_conn_type(StateData) ->
 case (StateData#state.sockmod):get_sockmod(StateData#state.socket) of
 gen_tcp -> c2s;
 p1_tls -> c2s_tls;
 ezlib ->
    case ezlib:get_sockmod((StateData#state.socket)#socket_state.socket) of
        gen_tcp -> c2s_compressed;
        p1_tls -> c2s_compressed_tls
    end;
 ejabberd_http_poll -> http_poll;
 ejabberd_http_bind -> http_bind;
 _ -> unknown
 end.
```

1. I want understand this function (good pythoner, never erlang) and add hack or pinpoint the issue: is sth ejabberd specific or sth with sockets (but others network tools/services works perfect).

   a) how can I insert to that function interactive debugger and get interactive introspection of stack and variables there.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're seeing says that the `get_conn_type` function doesn't exist in the `ejabberd_socket` module. And this is true; in the standard ejabberd distribution, `get_conn_type` lives in the `ejabberd_c2s` module.

If you are positive that neither you nor anyone else has modified the sources, then I would check your installation of Erlang. Perhaps it's broken, or you're using different versions to compile and run the code.

Comment: thanks, I saw "call to undefined function", but compilation was without errors, another ejabberd was installed from package also without errors - both are in different version and give me the same error.

Comment: Very strange. Try wiping out Erlang and reinstalling that. That's all I can think of -- that you might be getting useless error messages because of memory corruption from a bad .beam file.